# php getopt() function not giving correct answer

Tags: php

Following is my command line arguments:

```
php a.php -g UAMS ABC
```

Now when I get command from command line using getopt then I am getting only first argument i.e *UAMS*. I want to get both arguments i.e *UAMS* and *ABC*.

Following is my piece of code to get argument throug getopt() function.

```
$options=getopt("g");

echo "Options: ".json_encode($options);
```

I am only getting UAMS.

When I give argument like

```
php a.php -g a/b/c
```

Then I get arguments through `getopt` then it gives output as `a\/b\/c`?

So why it is not giving correct answer?

Comment: Run `php a.php -g "UAMS ABC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"g" is an option without values "g:" would be one with an optional value. See http://de.php.net/getopt

The backslashes are from json_encode().